# Isolated AC voltage measurement

Tags: ac, isolation, isolated

I'm looking to design a 120-300VAC power meter that uses an isolated DC supply (5VDC to 5VDC by Murata, 5.2kV) with an isolated SPI interface (ADUM4154, optocoupler in the diagram.) The AC line and neutral leads coming to my device will be controlled by TRIACs (switches in the attached diagram.) What will happen if only the line TRIAC switches closed? I figure this will take the entire circuit after the isolation to line voltage, but am wondering if any serious problems will occur.

My ADC (op-amp in schematic) is only configured to take in voltages in the range of +/-2.5VDC, but am thinking this would be the equivalent of 'zero volts' since the entire circuit is now floating at line voltage.

Will the isolated output of the Murata still be able to generate its '5VDC output' relative to the line voltage, or will it just not work completely?

I guess this question is analogous to taking any benchtop DMM, setting it to measure AC voltage, and just plugging in line without neutral.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your diagram is near enough useless as information to this question. The devil will be in the detail so, show a more representative schematic and add links for the device data sheets.

Comment: Fair enough, here are the isolated supplies: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/NXJ1S0505MC-R13?qs=ROOYoSPRM2vsYIPb2owhwA%3D%3D https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM4154.pdf

Comment: I would think this is theory-based enough that having these 2PNs should be enough. It's just the isolated side seeing Line Voltage without a Neutral

Comment: When switch off, no power. Nothing to measure. But if you need to continue some processes, it should be another source of energy for meter.  Add more details if you want answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line switch is closed, but the neutral is open, what will happen depends upon a) whether the neutral wire happens to be grounded, and b) whether any part of your circuit happens to be grounded. Neutral wires are often grounded at the utility transformer. Whether your circuit is grounded anywhere depends upon how you design your circuit.

If both the neutral wire, and your circuit have a ground in them, then you may expect to see your AC voltage even when the neutral switch is open, if the line switch is closed.

Note that standard practice is that if a power circuit is not fully insulated from the outside world, it should be enclosed in a metal container, which container should be grounded. If your circuit is intended for use by someone else, this may be a requirement, but I am not a lawyer, nor an electrician.

Also note that "solid-state switches" like triacs/SCRs are not perfect switches. Even when they are "off" or "open", they will conduct a little. if your ADC is sensitive in that it needs little current to make a measurement, it may "see" some of the AC supply voltage (reduced of course by your voltage divider) in spite of the fact that the triacs are "off".

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer! If Line and Neutral are coming from an isolated AC Power source (no ground), will my circuit just get brought up to Line Voltage?

Comment: What we generally think of as "Voltage" is a "potential difference". It is a difference in the electrical potential between two points. Yes, if you add (or subtract) enough electrons from your body, your hair will stand on end. But for electrical circuits, we can assume that such an "absolute" voltage plays no role. If you have an isolated AC power source, with no ground, and you attach one terminal only to a circuit, essentially, nothing will happen. It does have a potential difference (voltage) with respect to the other terminal, but that is a "so-what".

Comment: Ok, thanks. And I misspoke, I meant floating not isolated, so it doesn't have a ground wire

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I guess the second part of my question is: do you know how the isolated DC Power supply will react to seeing line at one of its output terminals? As you've said it's just line without a neutral so nothing should happen, but I'm curious to see if it can still generate the '5VDC Isolated' Output

Comment: If it is an isolated supply, and only one terminal is connected, the supply will see no load. But if it is an isolated supply, I'm not sure why you call one wire Line, and the other Neutral. In an isolated supply, each wire is equivalent, except that the wires are 180 degrees out of phase with one another.

Comment: Oh I'm saying that in this configuration, the isolated DC-DC converter will see the AC Line Voltage at its output terminal.

Comment: The isolated DC/DC converter is powering the ADC reading the AC Voltage. So I'm curious what happens to the output of this isolated DC/DC converter if just Line is applied on the right-hand side

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about the AC supply. One thing you need to remember is that "electrical switches" like triacs/SCRs are not perfect switches. Even when they are "off" or "open", they will conduct a little. if your ADC is sensitive in that it needs little current to make a measurement, it may "see" some of the AC supply voltage (reduced of course by your voltage divider) in spite of the fact that the triacs are "off". But the isolated DC-DC converter will not care whether one of both of the switches are open or closed.

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, thanks for all these answers it's really helpful. Maybe the simpler question I'm stuck on is, for this Isolated DC/DC Supply, what will happen if both it's Positive and Negative output terminals are tied to Line Voltage from a floating Power Supply: https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/NXF1S0505MC-R7?qs=fAHHVMwC%252BbiGBb9AV9FFLQ%3D%3D

Comment: i.e., will it still try to output '5VDC,' not output anything, or break

Comment: Yes, it will output 5VDC across it's two terminals. It will not break, because it is floating, or isolated (assuming you don't accidentally short it out, or apply the mains voltage across it's terminals).

Comment: Oh ok cool, that's really what was stumping me: if both the Positive and Negative Output Terminals of the isolated DC/DC see the Line Voltage, will they still be at 5VDC apart from each other. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by that last comment. By "Line voltage", I hope you do not mean the potential difference between Line and Neutral. Again, think of "voltage" as a potential difference between two points. In your circuit, regardless of which switches are open/closed, the 5VDC power supply never sees the potential difference between the Line and Neutral wires across its terminals.

Comment: Yes just the "Line Wire," not the Potential between Line and Neutral.